# Microsoft Excel cannot access the file: Excel VB FileOpen

Tags: excel, vba

My colleague gets this pop up error when he runs a macro in a spreadsheet;

> The file name or path does not exist

> The file is being used by another program.

> The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

None of these are true in my case.

My colleaguess desktop is running Windows 11 Enterprise 10.0.22621 and Excel 365 version 2312.

We have tried changing the highlighted part of the VB code to a UNC path instead of  a drive path but that hasn't worked.

**Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\Myserver01\pwr\Money\Cockpit\PositionCockpit.xlsm", Local:=True**

He does have read/write access to the location in question, on the error message box if he clicks on **End**, after 3 attempts it works.

Question is why does this keep happening?

[image]

[image]

**This is the code:**

```
Sub ImportProxy()
    Dim wCockpit As String, wEOD As String, dCurrentEOD As Date, vCalculationMode As Variant
    Dim sFolder As String
    vCalculationMode = Application.Calculation
    StartMacro
    wCockpit = Workbooks("PowerCockpit.xlsm").Name
    sFolder = "\\Server01\pwr\Moncey\Cockpit\FairCalculation\"
    'Import Daily
    Workbooks(wCockpit).Worksheets("FairProxy_daily").Cells.ClearContents
    If Workbooks(wCockpit).Worksheets("FairProxy").Range("FullExportPlusRun") = 3 Or Workbooks(wCockpit).Worksheets("FairProxy").Range("FullExportPlusRun") = 2 Or _
        Workbooks(wCockpit).Worksheets("FairProxy").Range("UpdateDA") = 1 Then
        Workbooks(wCockpit).Worksheets("FairProxy").Range("FullExportPlusRun") = ""
 
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=sFolder & "FairCalculation_PerDay.csv", Local:=True
        wEOD = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
        Workbooks(wCockpit).Activate
        Workbooks(wCockpit).Worksheets("FairProxy_daily").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Workbooks(wEOD).Close
    End If
    'Import PerProduct
    Workbooks(wCockpit).Worksheets("FairProxy_PerProduct").Cells.ClearContents
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=sFolder & "FairCalculation_PerProduct.csv", Local:=True
    wEOD = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
    Workbooks(wCockpit).Activate
    Workbooks(wCockpit).Worksheets("FairProxy_PerProduct").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks(wEOD).Close
    Workbooks(wCockpit).Worksheets("FairProxy").Select
    EndMacro
    CalculateWorkbook
    Application.Calculation = vCalculationMode
End Sub
```

Comment: Please paste your code as text so we can copy it for testing.

Comment: `Filename:=sFolder & "FairCalculation_PerDay.csv"`  In your posted code there's no backslash at the end of `sFolder`

Comment: HI @Tim Williams, should there be...?

Comment: Well is the file path actually `\Server01\pwr\Moncey\Cockpit\FairCalculationFairCalculation_PerProduct.csv` ?

Comment: ah lol, i corrected that mins after posting. Or attempted to...

Comment: I guess the edit is still pending...

Comment: The bolded line in your post isn't the same file as the highlighted line when the code errors? 
 `Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\Myserver01\pwr\Money\Cockpit\PositionCockpit.xlsm", Local:=True`  Code posted as text is not the same as your screenshot.

Comment: Hey Tim, consider this the correct UNC path: \\Myserver01\pwr\Money\Cockpit\PositionCockpit.xlsm"                                            I edited the original to protect the identity of the file owner as one of the folder names had his username in it.

Comment: If you still get an error with that single line by itself in a Sub then you could edit your question down to just that line.  If you run `Dir("\\Myserver01\pwr\Money\Cockpit\PositionCockpit.xlsm")` on the problem machine what do you get?

Comment: Thanks, i'll let you know when he's in tomorrow morning GMT.

Comment: Where is "FairCalculation_PerDay.csv" coming from? One common cause of "doesn't work/ does work" problems like this is that the csv file export hasn't completed.

Comment: Guys sincere apologies, I accidentally pasted the wrong statement. The affected code is the one in the [first] screenshot. Took me a while before i realised that the 2 were different.

Comment: Please *edit your question* to remove any "extra" code, and add the actual code which has the problem.  Right now it's difficult to see the screenshot, and the code posted as text is different.